# search a point from a list of Poligon using geodjango

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I am trying to develop a query builder using geodjango.  I want to find out whether a point is in a given list of multipolygon.  Django database API has "__in" to find data in a list.  Is there any similar geodjango query? If no, which is the best method to do this search.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#contains)

```
testpoint = Point(1.0, 2.0)
MyPolyTable.objects.filter(poly__contains=testpoint)
```